# Proving an identity involving differentials of integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

> Define $$ E(\theta,k) = \int_0^\theta \sqrt{1-k^2\sin{^2{x}}} dx$$ and $$F(\theta,k) = \int_0^\theta \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin{^2{x}}}} dx$$ We are to show $$\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial k}\right)_\theta = \frac{E-F}{k} $$

Am I right in thinking: $$\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial k}\right)_\theta =\int_0^\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial k}\sqrt{1-k^2\sin{^2{x}}} dx $$

Which gives $$k\left[\int_0^\theta \frac{\cos^2{x}}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin{^2{x}}}} dx - \int_0^\theta \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin{^2{x}}}} dx\right]$$

which is $$k\left[\int_0^\theta \frac{\cos^2{x}}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin{^2{x}}}} dx -F\right]$$

However, I can't seem to reduce the left integral to give what is required. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your first lethal weapon (i.e adding and subtracting one):
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{dk}\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2x}&=-\frac{k\sin^2x}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2x}}\\
&=\frac{1}{k}\frac{1-k^2\sin^2x-1}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2x}}\\
&=\frac{1}{k}\biggl(\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2x}}\biggr)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Fantastic! Many thanks for your help. The amount of times the adding or subtracting 1 trick has came up is really frustrating! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your correct assumption
$$\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial k}\right)_\theta =\int_0^\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial k}\sqrt{1-k^2\sin{^2{x}}}\ dx$$
the differential, however, evaluates to
$$\begin{align}\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial k}\right)_\theta &=\int_0^\theta \frac{-k\sin^2\theta}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin{^2{x}}}}\ dx\\&=\frac{1}{k}\int_0^\theta \frac{-k^2\sin^2\theta}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin{^2{x}}}}\ dx\\&=\frac{1}{k}\int_0^\theta \frac{1-k^2\sin^2\theta-1}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin{^2{x}}}}\ dx\\&=\frac{1}{k}\left(\int_0^\theta \sqrt{1-k^2\sin{^2{x}}}\ dx-\int_0^\theta \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin{^2{x}}}}\ dx\right)\\&=\frac{E-F}{k}\end{align}$$

Comment: Your help is much appreciated kind sir!

Comment: You are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The calculation of $\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial k}\right)_{\theta}$ is fine, although you may not want to use $-\sin^2 x = \cos^2 x - 1$.  Instead, calculate $\frac{E-F}{k}$ directly by combining the integrals and simplifying.

Comment: I see. If we were to suppose we weren't given the result, is there anyway to get to it or would it just be some messy algebra?

Comment: As you can see in mickep and Alijah's answers, you can obtain the result from the derivative only.  I'm not an expert in elliptic integrals, so it's hard for me to say what kind of simplification of the derivative you would expect if you didn't know what final form you were looking for.